# WPF- Why aren't these styles working?

Tags: wpf, styles

I am trying to set a global style for multiple control derived types by putting this in my app.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackgroundBrush, Source={x:Static m:Settings.Instance}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ForegroundBrush, Source={x:Static m:Settings.Instance}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding ForegroundBrush, Source={x:Static m:Settings.Instance}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />
```

Right now the window style only works in the visual studio design window and the button style doesn't work at all. What have I done wrong?

Comment: what version of Visual Studio & .NET Framework are you using? I've been having problems getting styles to work with .NET 4.0 (WPF 4.0). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239714/why-cant-i-style-a-control-with-the-aero-theme-applied-in-wpf-4-0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found sometimes that BasedOn is rather particular.
If you assign a key then it tends to work more often.
I'm not sure if the value bindings are causing your issue as i didn't make and external static class to use.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="simpleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="CornflowerBlue" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" BasedOn="{StaticResource simpleStyle}" />

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource simpleStyle}" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource simpleStyle}" />
</Grid.Resources>
<Button Height="50" Width="100">
    Hello
</Button>
```