# WPF ComboBox does not respect Background setter on Windows 10

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, xaml, combobox

I have a simple ComboBox, the source is attached below:

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Background="Red" Height="20" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="A"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="B"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="C"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

On Windows 7/Server 2008, the ComboBox is shown with a red background. When running the exact same code or binaries on Windows 10, the ComboBox loses the red background and becomes grey.

[image: Win 7 Win10 Combobox example]

How can I get the Win10 background to become red, and do so in a manner which will not break the Win7 code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combobox background not being applied in windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183746/combobox-background-not-being-applied-in-windows-8)