# Detect Aero or Classic theme in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, themes

I found questions on how to load a resource dictionary to apply a specific windows theme, [such as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239714/why-cant-i-style-a-control-with-the-aero-theme-applied-in-wpf-4-0), but I don't want to load the resource dictionary for aero if the windows theme is already set to aero, is it possible do something in code behind that can determine what the current windows theme is?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [DwmIsCompositionEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969518%28VS.85%29.aspx) function... it will work for currently active user only.

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr DwmIsCompositionEnabled(out bool pfEnabled);

bool aeroEnabled = false;

if (NativeMethods.DwmIsCompositionEnabled(out aeroEnabled) == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    //Some code here
}
```